# Remove an Array from COOKIE PHP

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I need to delete a cookie array but the code I did is not working.

I do have a cookie array, the array result is:

```
cart => Array
(
    [2] => Array
      (
        [0] => {"item_id":2,"item_size":2,"item_quantities":2,"item_note":"","item_extra":[3,2,1]}
        [1] => {"item_id":2,"item_size":2,"item_quantities":2,"item_note":"","item_extra":[2,1]}
        [2] => {"item_id":2,"item_size":1,"item_quantities":2,"item_note":"","item_extra":[2]}
      )

    [1] => Array
      (
        [0] => {"item_id":1,"item_size":0,"item_quantities":3,"item_note":"","item_extra":0}
      )

)
```

I want to remove this particular item from the cookie array

```
[1] => {"item_id":2,"item_size":2,"item_quantities":2,"item_note":"","item_extra":[2,1]}
```

what I did is that:

```
$cart = 2;
$item = 1;
unset($_COOKIE['cart'][$cart][$item]);
setcookie("cart[{$cart}][{$item}]", "", 1);
```

I appreciate your help
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have review this and looks like in same request you have and set and unset the cookie? Because what happened if you do in same request then first it's set the cookie and then remove so on every request same things happened so it's not work for you.
Please find the image for the cookie headers:
[image]

So you need to do code like below:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['cart'][0])) {
    setcookie("cart[0][0]", "", time()-7200);    
} else {
    setcookie("cart[0][0]", "test0", time() + (86400 * 365));    
}
```

Also, from php side it's delete but from the browser it's not delete then it again send the cookie into the request so that's why it's displaying you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your good interest and try your best for helping me, I did remove the whole cookie system and start from scratch. and what I do is remove the array cookie and add a normal cookie with son encode array inside it and now it works fine for me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Both the way you have used it's correct so use any of one

1. unset($_COOKIE['cart'][$cart][$item]);
2. setcookie("cart[{$cart}][{$item}]", "", 1);

After that you want check like it's working or not you can check with the var_dump($_COOKIE['cart']);

If you want to delete the full cart then you can simply use unset($_COOKIE['cart']);

Comment: that what I did but when I refresh the page the cookie still there

Comment: You need pass the updated cookies into the response so when you refresh the page then see the latest cookie value

Comment: Is it still any issue with this solution?

Comment: still, the same problem when I refresh the page the cookie appears

Comment: You have passed the updated cookie into the response? Can you please pass example full code for this so i can check?

Comment: I have add new answer for this so can you please check this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61919260/11710118

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a cookie like that:

```
setcookie("cart[{$p_id}][]", json_encode($data), time() + (86400 * 365));
```

and I do this to remove it:

```
setcookie("cart[{$cart}][{$item}]", json_encode([]), 1);
unset($_COOKIE['cart'][$cart][$item]);
```

I tried this also:

```
// this
setcookie("cart[{$cart}][{$item}]", "", 1);
unset($_COOKIE['cart'][$cart][$item]);
// and this
setcookie("cart[{$cart}][{$item}]", "", 1, "/");
unset($_COOKIE['cart'][$cart][$item]);
// and this
setcookie("cart[{$cart}][{$item}]", "",  time() - (86400 * 365));
unset($_COOKIE['cart'][$cart][$item]);
```

I also tried to delete the whole cookie like that:

```
unset($_COOKIE['cart']);
setcookie('cart', '', time() - 3600, '/');
```

Nothing happened and I'm using the MAMP server